# Django Python Version 3.6.10 to 3.6.11 Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django application deployed in Heroku, it has been deployed for months without any issue. Deployments today are suddenly failing saying Heroku doesn't support Python 3.6.10, only 3.6.11 (closest one to 3.6.10)

I have not specified a version anywhere in my app so I can only assume Django defaults to 3.6.10 or Heroku previously did, but they have abruptly stopped supporting it now.

Are there any risks in setting 3.6.11 in my runtime file so my builds work? Is there any reason it defaults to 3.6.10?

The app is in use heavily and Heroku support is awful unless you pay 1000 a month so I can't afford it to fail, and if it does, I can't revert to 3.6.10!

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: Check your [`runtime.txt`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) file

Comment: Hi, thank you, I've never set one. So it defaulted some how, that's why I'm nervous about changing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#python-versions-and-upgrades) say your app continues to use the same Python version as when it was first deployed. In your case, the default would have been 3.6.10 when you first deployed your app, and this is no longer available. You can explicitly upgrade to 3.6.11 by creating a `runtime.txt` file.

It should be safe to upgrade between Python 3.6.X versions. If you want to be sure, then you could deploy a separate app on Python 3.6.11, or create a virtualenv locally and test on Python 3.6.11.

> I can only assume Django defaults to 3.6.10

Django isn't controlling the Python version that Heroku is using. Each version of Django supports a range of Python versions. Check the release notes for your version.

Comment: Thank you, I'm shocked they've discontinued a version within 8 weeks of me deploying! Your answer is very helpful